# Cant delete files from folder using unlink function in php

Tags: php

Unable to delete file from folder otherwise code work perfectly.
same code i used for replacing or updating image where it works fine but here dosent able to delete data from folder by their id or name

```
if(isset($_POST['8maths_delete']))   //post method button name
{
    $id = $_POST['delete_id']; //data fetch by id
    $files_query = "DELETE FROM 8maths WHERE id='$id'";  //deleting data from sever
    $files_query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $files_query); //query run
    if($files_query_run) // query run
    {
               unlink("upload/".$row['files']); //unlink where upload folder where all the files held. but dosent able to delete file from folder
               $_SESSION['success'] = "Your Data is Deleted"; //session for echo
               header('Location: 8thmaths.php'); 
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['status'] = "Your Data is not Deleted";       
        header('Location: 8thmaths.php'); //redirecting location
    }    
}
```

Comment: is folder empty? if not, you must delete file before use unlink

Comment: what is the path of the file you are attempting to delete? Try using the full path like /var/www/html/{project folder}/uploads/file.jpg for example.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['8maths_delete']))
{
$id = $_POST['delete_id'];
$files_query = "DELETE FROM 8maths WHERE id='$id'";
$files_query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $files_query);
if($files_query_run)
{
unlink("upload/".$row['files']);
$_SESSION['success'] = "Your Data is Deleted";
$_SESSION['status_code'] = "success";
header('Location: 8thmaths.php'); 
 }
else
{
 $_SESSION['status'] = "Your Data is not Deleted";       
        $_SESSION['status_code'] = "error"; header('Location: 8thmaths.php');  }    
}
here is the full code but when i update an image it delete pre

Comment: please update your questions with the code, do not post is a a comment it is very difficult to read

Comment: plz help m stuck their

Comment: var_dump the unlink result like so var_dump(unlink("upload/".$row['files'])); to see if return an error. Also check apache error log (https://blog.codeasite.com/how-do-i-find-apache-http-server-log-files/)

Comment: you tried it chmod 777 folde_file?

Comment: you should use escape string to id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues I can see:

1 - You reference $row['files'] but I don't see $row defined anywhere in your code.

2 - Using the word 'files' I assume there could be multiple, if that's the case you need to loop over all the files and unlink them either with something like:

A foreach loop:

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($files_query_run, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach($result as $row) {
    unlink("upload/".$row['files']);
}
```

Or using a while loop.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($files_query_run)){
        unlink("upload/".$row['files']);
    }
```

I hope this helps get you off to the right start.

Comment: You're welcome. If this is the accepted answer, kindly mark it appropriately. This way, people aren't looking to answer something already solved .